# Images in tags don't show on mail when send template using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, email, thymeleaf

I trying to send mail using Thymeleaf. Html template parsed and look good, but images show only alt text. In image text I used that code:

```
<img src="img/headershopgo.png"  class="img-fluid " alt="header image with Aldi logo"  
th:src="|cid:${headershopgo}|" /> (I put here also <img src="/static/img/headershopgo.png")
```

That is my code part:

```
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("name", "Volodymyr");
String process = templateEngine.process("bonnetjeEN", context);

helper.setText(process, true);
helper.addInline("headershopgo",new 
ClassPathResource("static/img/headershopgo.png"),"image/png");
```

but on my mail i receive temaplte without images and addInline() method pin images below(showes on Image [template on received mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMm4m.png))

Comment: For clarification: (1) What does `${headershopgo}` evaluate to? I would expect it to be the string `headershopgo`, since that needs to exactly match `addInline("headershopgo"...`. (2) Does `new ClassPathResource("static/img/headershopgo.png")` evaluate correctly to the image file?

Comment: hi. I resolve my issue when I remove th:src="|cid:${headershopgo}|, change <img src="img/headershopgo.png" to img src ="cid:headershoplogo" and when configured mail agent to recive it not on spam folder. But I get another problem, maybe you knov how solve. After add inline file I lost opportunity to get attach file

Comment: ok. ty. I'll create new question